# Using Abstract Class and super()

Tags: java, abstract-class, shapes, super

I have created an abstract shape class for 2d game but i am getting an error in both the shape classes. The error is something to do with super(). There maybe other errors as well. i have also shown where i get the error in the code. IS super() suitable to use.

Shape class

```
public abstract class Shape {

    int Y;
    int WIDTH;
    int HEIGHT;
    int DIAMETER;

    public Shape(int Y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, int DIAMETER) {
        this.Y = Y;
        this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
        this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
        this.DIAMETER = DIAMETER;
    }

    public abstract void paint(Graphics g);

}
```

Racquet class

```
public class Racquet extends Shape {

    int x = 0;
    int xa = 0;
    private Game game;

    public Racquet(int Y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
        super(Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT); // <- **Error Here**

    }

    public void move() {
        if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth() - this.WIDTH)
            x = x + xa;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics r) {
        r.setColor(new java.awt.Color(229, 144, 75));
        r.fillRect(x, Y, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, this.Y, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
    }

    public int getTopY() {
        return this.Y - this.HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

Ball Class

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Ball extends Shape {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xa = 1;
    int ya = 1;
    private Game game;

    public Ball(Integer DIAMETER) {
        super(DIAMETER); // <- **Error Here**
    }

    void move() {
        if (x + xa < 0)
            xa = game.speed;
        if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - this.DIAMETER)
            xa = -game.speed;
        if (y + ya < 0)
            ya = game.speed;
        if (y + ya > game.getHeight() - this.DIAMETER)
            game.CheckScore();
        if (collision()) {
            ya = -game.speed;
            y = game.racquet.getTopY() - this.DIAMETER;
            game.speed++;
        }
        x = x + xa;
        y = y + ya;

    }

    private boolean collision() {
        return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics b) {

        b.setColor(new java.awt.Color(237, 238, 233));
        b.fillOval(x, y, this.DIAMETER, this.DIAMETER);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, this.DIAMETER, this.DIAMETER);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, post the error. Is it compile time or run time error? Ok, I see `super(Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);` // <- **Error Here** You have to provide 4 parameters, not 3.

Comment: The error message tells exactly what is wrong. No need to guess. Just read it. Your base class constructor expects 4 arguments. You're passing 3, or 1. It needs 4.

Comment: Thanks you are right. Ok how do i go about fixing this as i have two shape classes. @SergeiSirik

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer below. Either implement 2 more constructors with 1 and 3 parameters in your `Shape` class, or call `super(...)` with 4 parameters.

Answer (score 6):

By calling `super(...)`, you are actually calling constructor of super class. In the super class you have only one constructor which expects 4 parameters: `Shape(int Y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, int DIAMETER)`, so you either have to provide 4 parameters when calling `super(...)`, or provide needed constructors in the super class, with 3 parameters and with 1 parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your Shape class doesn't have constructor with three parameters or one parameters.
You may want to use;

in recquet class

```
super(Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);
```

in Ball class

```
super(0, 0, 0, DIAMETER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shape doesn't have constructors that fit the parameters you are using in Racquet and Ball.
From a "best-practice" perspective, since Ball and Racquet should logically be constructed differently, it may be better to use composition, rather than inheritance.